# UTF-8 workflow issue

Tags: html, database, utf-8, character-encoding, innodb

I have a situation wherein my inclusion of accented characters works in my HTML, but fails on text imported from the database.

The HTML text encoding assignment is the same as I have always used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
…
```

And when I enter a word such as "téléphone" directly in the HTML, it works as well as it always has.

If that same word comes from a database, it becomes "t?l?phone". (The "?" shows as a black diamond with a question mark within.)

Based on this, I assume I have a workflow encoding error. However, I'm surprised not to find much on the googlizer or SO regarding this.

My database consists of InnoDB tables encoded in utf8_unicode_ci.

I want to be able to include a variety of European scripts, including cyrillic, hence the utf8_unicode_ci.

I'm a bit lost at this point.

Au secours?

Comment: See "question mark" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)